# libcurl curl/curl.h No such file or Directory Win xp 32 MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, libcurl

I have been searching for a couple of hours and found several threads with the same problem and tried all their suggestions.

My curl.h is in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\curl-7.29.0\include\curl and I've included it at compile time but for some reason gcc claims it can't find it:

```
gcc -o curl.exe curl.c -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/ -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/curl-7.29.0/lib/.libs/ -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/curl-7.29.0/include/curl -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/OpenSSL-Win32/ -lcurl -lws2_32
```

and the result:

```
curl.c:4:32: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE:** (With the suggestion from H2CO3)

```
$ gcc -o curl.exe curl.c -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/curl-7.29.0/lib/.libs/ -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/curl-7.29.0/include/ -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/OpenSSL-Win32/include/ -lws2_32

C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x245): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formfree'
C:\DOCUME~1\J10441\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccHP6WWt.o:curl.c:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
```

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

If I try to compile with -lcurl it says ..... ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl is this because it can't find the dll?

Comment: Note: the header file has nothing to do with the DLL. Google "C compilation process" and read and embrace that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including `<curl/curl.h>`, and **not** `<curl.h>`. So you have to tell the compiler to look for header files in the `include` directory, and **not** in `include/curl`:

```
gcc -IC:\MinGW\msys\1.0\curl-7.29.0\include etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be beyond the scope of what you're doing, but, I found it best to install a version of cURL(libcurl) into the MinGW/MSYS environment. After installed, any program can be compiled to use it with the typical <curl/curl.h> and -lcurl conventions since it's installed where GCC would expect it. I documented my process [here](http://cacogenics.blogspot.com/2015/02/using-libcurl-openssl-and-gtk-with-mingw.html).